# Why is Java Runtime.exec command working but ProcessBuilder not able to execute the Perforce client command?

Tags: java, perforce, processbuilder, runtime.exec

Ok, so to delete a Perfoce Label , the CommandLine command is: `p4 label -d mylabel123`.
Now I want to execute this command using Java. I tried `Runtime.exec()` and it works like charm. However when I run the same command using `ProcessBuilder` it doesn't work. Any help appreciated.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        exec1("p4 label -d mylabel123");
        exec2("p4","label -d mylabel123");
    }
    public static void exec1(String cmd)
            throws java.io.IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Executing Runtime.exec()");
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                proc.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                proc.getErrorStream()));

        String s = null;
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
             System.out.println(s);
        }
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
             System.out.println(s);
        }
        proc.waitFor();
    }
    public static void exec2(String... cmd) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        System.out.println("\n\nExecuting ProcessBuilder.start()");
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
        pb.inheritIO();
        pb.command(cmd);
        Process process = pb.start();
        process.waitFor();
    }
}
```

Method exec1() output: *Label mylabel123 deleted.*

Method exec2() output: *Unknown command.  Try 'p4 help' for info.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ProcessBuilder` wants you to provide the command name and each argument as separate strings.  When you (indirectly) perform

```
pb.command("p4", "label -d mylabel123");
```

you are building a process that runs command `p4` with a single argument, `label -d mylabel123`.  You want instead to run that command with three separate arguments:

```
pb.command("p4", "label", "-d", "mylabel123");
```

Your clue would have been that the error message in the second case is emitted by the `p4` command (it says "Try 'p4 help' for info").  Clearly, then, the problem is with the arguments.  I grant you, though, that `p4` does create some confusion by calling one of its arguments a "command".